# cakephp pagination sort descending first

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

By default when you click on the sort field in pagination it will sort ascending first, is there a way to set it to descending first?

```
<th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Views', 'views'); ?></th>
```

I want my users to see most viewed first after clicking on view sort not least viewed.

Answer (score 6):

To set the default sort direction to be descending, change your code above to this:

```
<th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Views', 'views, array('direction' => 'desc')); ?></th>
```

Once activated, the sort direction will toggle between descending and ascending as usual.